# Azure Pipelines [error] Not found Unity Editor Directory: /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2017.4.27f1

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, file-not-found

I am trying to setup pipeline in Azure pipelines for Unity 3d project for iOS platform.
I selected MacOS host agent for building my pipeline.Then I am continuously getting this error saying:

> ##[error]Not found Unity Editor Directory: /Applications/Unity/Hub/Editor/2017.4.27f1

I already tried installing Unity Hub and Editor using command line , but it is not working and giving same error.

I am attaching a screenshot of the error and build pipeline.

Anyone tried this and got through it.Thanks in advance for help.

[image: Azure pipeline steps]

[image: Error while building]